# Change theme for Jekyll static site

Tags: jekyll, github-pages

I set up my User site on github-pages with the default "minima" theme - works just fine. However, I can't figure out how to change themes. Tried following [these instructions](https://github.com/pages-themes/architect) to change theme to "architect":

To use the Architect theme:

1. Add the following to your site's _config.yml:
   `theme: jekyll-theme-architect`
2. Optionally, if you'd like to preview your site on your computer, add the following to your site's Gemfile:
   `gem "github-pages", group: :jekyll_plugins`

Seems really simple, right? But when I commit the changes and reload the page at `http://username.github.io` it's just a blank page.

I'm sure I'm missing something really obvious but if you can explain I would greatly appreciate it!

Answer (score 1):

The theme you chose has only one layout, that is the `default` layout, while the **minima** theme has three, `default`, `post` and `page`.

Just change the layouts used by your posts and pages to `default` in their frontmatter or globally in the configuration.

Comment: Thanks for your reply. After setting `theme: jekyll-theme-architect` setting page and post layouts to `default` just made the posts disappear and did not change the homepage theme.

Comment: See this blog post: https://surfacedetail.blogspot.com/2019/04/github-pages-and-jekyll-themes.html

Comment: Did you change the layout of your 'index' page to default as well?

Answer (score 1):

you can't change the theme of an active jekyll site. you need to install a new theme when you create the site. it's kind of annoying, but if you're just getting started with the site, installing a new theme shouldn't be too difficult.